# Get the last non-null value per row of a 2D Numpy array

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have a 2D numpy array that looks like

```
a = np.array(
    [
        [1,2,np.nan,np.nan],
        [1,33,45,np.nan],
        [11,22,3,78],
    ]
)
```

I need to extract the last non null value per row i.e.
[2, 45, 78]

Please guide on how to get it.

thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If `np.nan` are always trailing: `a[np.diff(np.isnan(a), append=True, axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into two sub-problems.

1. Remove `nan`s from each row
2. Select last element from the array

```py
[r[~np.isnan(r)][-1] for r in a]
```

produces

```
[2.0, 45.0, 78.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a vectorial solution, you can try:

```
# get the index of last nan
idx = np.argmax(~np.isnan(a)[:, ::-1], axis=1)

# slice
a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), a.shape[1]-idx-1]
```

output: `array([ 2., 45., 78.])`